# WTF is WTF-Forms?

Tags: discussion

There exist the tags [wtforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wtforms) and [flask-wtforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-wtforms) that contain 708 or 587 questions, respectively. Quite a few of these questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231010/generating-a-csrf-token-manually-with-flask-wtf-forms), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196488/flask-wtfforms-initial-values-for-field-list), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733201/importerror-when-importing-flask-wtf-forms)) do prefer the phrasing `WTF-Forms`, `WTFForms`, or forms of this before `WTForms`. It seems to be absolutely clear that `WTF` is an abbreviation for `WTForms` in this context. I wonder WTF people tend to think that `WTF-Forms` is a correct phrase that can be used in this context. How can this happen and how can we prevent this?

Comment: *"How can this happen"* - people created those tags. *"How can we prevent this"* - people creating tags? Why would we want to? A better question might be *"what can we do about this specific case"*, to which the answer is setting synonyms.

Comment: The tags are right, but people are messing up the acronym in their posts. Edit to fix or ignore- your choice. Its a common problem: [RAS Syndrome (Redundant Acronym Syndrome Syndrome)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome)

Comment: As the co-author of WTForms, I can also add that some 11 years ago,  when we were writing the library as a little set of helpers for a project we were doing, A) I was a college student and B) I thought "What the Forms?" was a hilarious name. (We later dropped any mention of the origination of the name, but that's where it came from.) That it turned out to be one of the most popular form processing frameworks for Flask/Werkzeug was not intended originally, but kinda neat.

Answer (score 6):

It's not [wtf-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wtf-forms). There is no hyphen and there is only one `f`. But it *is* [Flask-WTF](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (maybe we need a synonym?).

Don't confuse it with [WTF ORMs](https://what.thedailywtf.com/topic/19594/orms).

It appears to be [a Python library](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms):

> WTForms is a flexible forms validation and rendering library for python web development.

Of course, the name may be the source of some of these questions. You need to have:

```
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, validators
```

not:

```
from wtfforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, validators
```

---

While we can all mock them for their poor name, the tag is perfectly on-topic for Stack Overflow.

**Like any other spelling mistake** (`java  script` is a particularly annoying one), **the posts should be edited to fix the errors.** You have 2k+ rep, so you are as able as anyone to do so.

I'm not concerned about this harming the SEO; [Google knows the right name](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wtfforms).

Comment: wtf? I have never confused `wtforms` with `WTF ORMs`, and I know that it is called `wtforms` and not `wtf-forms`. Your answer does not provide any useful information to me.

Comment: @returntrue The important part is right in the middle, "Like any other spelling mistake (java  script is a particularly annoying one), the posts should be edited to fix the errors."

Comment: Then the answer should be narrowed down to the important parts only.

Comment: @returntrue Meta allows for a bit more "fluff" than main, but I still think that most of the information is relevant to people who are unfamiliar with the technology. It was unclear what exactly you were asking about ("this"???). I have moved the "most important part" downwards and emphasized it.